# how to sync a mobile app's database with main server's database

Tags: c#, database, web-services, synchronizationcontext

I have building an app that will help employees collect money from customers according to their balance. The app should be working on offline from internet. And when It becomes online, it should sends its collection records to the main server's database.

there are 5 thousands customers in the main DB and customers' balances are always changing. How should I sync between mobile app's db and main server's db? Should I truncate mobile apps' database and get all the records from the main server and insert them into the mobile? Or should I do an Update operation for each client? By the way, a new client can be created as well at any time?

Which way is more efficient?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: in mobile, I am using sqlce and I am using SQL SERVER in main server

Comment: Have a look at MS's Sync Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854.aspx